# fputcsv not displaying mysql table from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently made a website and have a members table in my sql. I have an admin page that has the ability to download that with column names; however I used to use INTO OUTFILE but that is not allowed on my host. I came up with this code to download the file:

```
if(file_exists('downloads/members_'.date("m-d-Y").'.csv') == true) {
    header("Location: /downloads/members_".date("m-d-Y").".csv");
}   

$output = fopen('downloads/members_'.date("m-d-Y").'.csv', 'w+');

fputcsv($output, array('memberID','username', 'password', 'email', 'active', 'resetToken', 'resetComplete', 'support', 'supportToken' ));

$rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output,$row);
header("Location: /downloads/members_".date("m-d-Y").".csv");
exit;
```

This just outputs the column names and I have never used fputcsv before and am a tad confused on what I am doing wrong. I get the file to download but not with the table in it.

[EDIT] I just tried it with a valid sql query and it does not work. updated code above. Also There is stuff in the members table.

Comment: Are you sure result set from query is not empty?

Comment: This is _not_ a valid sql statement: `SELECT * FROM 'members';`.

Comment: Have you tested my answer? If it does not work, tell me your errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members", $connection);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=yourcsv.csv');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    $csvoutput = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $row = getRow($result);
    $headers = array_keys($row);//columns from db e.g, memberID','username',...
    fputcsv($csvoutput, $headers);
    fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);
    while ($row = getRow($result)) {
        fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);
    }
    fclose($csvoutput);
    exit;
   }
```

Here is your getRow() function:

```
 function getRow($res){
     return mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   }
```

And in your html:

```
<input type="submit" name="download" value="Download CSV">
```

Here is realtime demo with sqllite3 database. Uncomment the create database and insert statement in order to see the working [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6adj-sug3). I have tested and it is working fine. I hope this will help you.

Comment: It outputs an blank/invalid csv

Comment: I have updated my answer with working demo. If it helps, please click the tick icon above.